# while run the api Internal Server Error is shown

Tags: android

```
    public class MaterialSupportapi extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
       @Override
       protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
           MaterialJson JSONOBJECT = new MaterialJson();
            name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_name);
            mobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_contactnumber);
            street = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_address1);
            city = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_address2);
            state = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_address3);
            zipcode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_address4);
           day=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1_Day);
            month = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2_month);
           time_from = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3_time_from);
            time_to = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner4_time_to);
           JSONOBJECT.setName(name.getText().toString());
           JSONOBJECT.setMobile(mobile.getText().toString());
           JSONOBJECT.setStreet(street.getText().toString());
           JSONOBJECT.setCity(city.getText().toString());
           JSONOBJECT.setState(state.getText().toString());
           JSONOBJECT.setZipcode(zipcode.getText().toString());
           JSONOBJECT.setDay(day.getSelectedItem().toString());
           JSONOBJECT.setMonth(month.getSelectedItem().toString());
           JSONOBJECT.setTimeFrom(time_from.getSelectedItem().toString());
           JSONOBJECT.setTimeTo(time_to.getSelectedItem().toString());
           JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
           try {
               obj.put("name",JSONOBJECT.getName());
               obj.put("mobile",JSONOBJECT.getMobile());
               obj.put("day",JSONOBJECT.getDay());
               obj.put("month",JSONOBJECT.getMonth());
               obj.put("time_from",JSONOBJECT.getTimeFrom());
               obj.put("time_to",JSONOBJECT.getTimeTo());
               obj.put("street",JSONOBJECT.getStreet());
               obj.put("city",JSONOBJECT.getCity());
               obj.put("state",JSONOBJECT.getState());
               obj.put("zipcode",JSONOBJECT.getZipcode());
               // obj.put("type",JSONOBJECT.getType());

           } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           //Toast.makeText(this, obj.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
           HttpPost httput = new HttpPost("https://vaananba.herokuapp.com/api/materialsupport");
           StringEntity se = null;
           try {
               se = new StringEntity(obj.toString());
           } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           httput.setEntity(se);
           httput.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
           int a = 0;
           try {
               HttpResponse resp = httpclient.execute(httput);
                /*a = resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                return a;*/
               String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());
               //a = resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
               return responseBody.toString();

           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           return null;
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           //TextView aa= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
           //aa.setText(result);
           // Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_iamsupport);
           //submit.setText(result);
           Toast.makeText(MaterialSupport.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           //Toast.makeText(IamSupport.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() {}
   }
```

this is my code,while run the file it shows internal server error.i gave toast message to check whether it takes all the details,but it shows internal server error and i gave user permission in manifest also

03-10 11:53:55.055    6520-6524/? E/dalvikvm﹕ heapsize setIdealFootprint overhead 6733824
03-10 11:53:56.116    7795-7795/com.myapps.materialapplication E/dalvikvm﹕ heapsize setIdealFootprint max1 9109504
03-10 11:53:56.116    7795-7795/com.myapps.materialapplication E/dalvikvm﹕ heapsize setIdealFootprint max2 9109504
03-10 11:53:56.116    7795-7795/com.myapps.materialapplication E/dalvikvm﹕ heapsize setIdealFootprint overhead 6733824
03-10 11:53:56.176    7795-7795/com.myapps.materialapplication E/dalvikvm﹕ heapsize setIdealFootprint max1 9648128
03-10 11:53:56.176    7795-7795/com.myapps.materialapplication E/dalvikvm﹕ heapsize setIdealFootprint max2 9648128
03-10 11:53:56.176    7795-7795/com.myapps.materialapplication E/dalvikvm﹕ heapsize setIdealFootprint overhead 6733824
03-10 11:53:56.236    7795-7795/com.myapps.materialapplication E/dalvikvm﹕ heapsize setIdealFootprint max1 10200064
03-10 11:53:56.236    7795-7795/com.myapps.materialapplication E/dalvikvm﹕ heapsize setIdealFootprint max2 10200064
03-10 11:53:56.236    7795-7795/com.myapps.materialapplication E/dalvikvm﹕ heapsize setIdealFootprint overhead 6733824
03-10 11:54:21.771      687-689/? E/dalvikvm﹕ heapsize setIdealFootprint overhead 6733824

this is my logcat error

Comment: Can you post logcat trace.

Comment: @Gunaseelan k sure sir

Answer (score 0):

Internal Server error is not client side but it is from server, when you have request code 500 from server side you will have Internal Server Error message comes. Can you please print your response code in the log and check is should be 500. Please check your server side as well because you may miss some parameters or may be some parameters value is going null.

hope this will helo you.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply.

Comment: you are welcome, accept the answer if it helps you in resolving your issue. Also i have seen bad programming in your given code.

Comment: you are creating object of the   MaterialJson JSONOBJECT = new MaterialJson(); and then putting data in the settter method of that class, and again you are taking value of those for creating json object. so in short you are doing set and get both in the same place, better you directly set the value in jsonObject.